# How do I disable the Exchange Powershell "Tip of the Day"?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

When starting Powershell you get the "Tip of the Day". How do I disable this? I Googled, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found it here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\Exchange.ps1

Line 291 and 291 I commented out with the hash character (#):

```
# get-exbanner 
# get-tip
```

Comment: I also had to do the same thing with remoteexchange.ps1 in the same folder.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI, if you do edit that file RemoteExchange.ps1

Any user that starts PowerShell will not receive the banner or the tip unless specified in their PowerShellProfile.ps1

Comment: You're right: it's just an FYI. Wouldn't this be more suitable information as a comment on another answer to expand on.

Answer (score -1):

the file that needs to be updated is remoteexchange.ps1

Comment: Could you be more complete? ;)